# read not prompting when i/p redirected from a file

Tags: linux, bash

I have this:

```
while read -r line; do echo "hello $line"; read -p "Press any key" -n 1; done < file

hello This is line 1
hello his is line 2
hello his is line 3
hello his is line 4
hello his is line 5
hello his is line 6
hello his is line 7
```

Why do I not see the prompt "Press any key" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from `man bash`:

```
-p prompt
   Display prompt on standard error, without a trailing new
   line, before attempting to read any input. The prompt is
   displayed only if input is coming from a terminal.
```

So, because you read lines from file but not from terminal prompt not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, you don't see the prompt because bash only prints the prompt when stdin is a terminal.  In your case, stdin is a file.

But there's a bigger bug here:  It seems to me that you want to read from two places:  a file and the user.  You'll have to do some redirection magic to accomplish this:

```
# back up stdin
exec 3<&0
# read each line of a file.  the IFS="" prevents read from
# stripping leading and trailing whitespace in the line
while IFS="" read -r line; do
    # use printf instead of echo because ${line} might have
    # backslashes in it which some versions of echo treat
    # specially
    printf '%s\n' "hello ${line}"
    # prompt the user by reading from the original stdin
    read -p "Press any key" -n 1 <&3
done <file
# done with the stdin backup, so close the file descriptor
exec 3<&-
```

Note that the above code won't work with `/bin/sh` because it's not POSIX compliant.  You'll have to use bash.  I'd recommend making it POSIX compliant by changing the line that prompts the user:

```
printf 'Press enter to continue' >&2
read <&3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may explicitly read from the controlling terminal `/dev/tty`:

```
while IFS="" read -r line; do 
   echo "hello $line"
   read -p "Press any key" -n 1 </dev/tty
done < file
```